# Can't figure out why the "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread" error appears in Python program

Tags: python, pyqt

I've made a simple pyqt gui, with threading, and I can't understand what I need to change in my code to avoid the "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread" error. I have a feeling that this error occurs because of QMainWindow, but I'm not sure.

This is my code.

```
import sys,time, threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
      
    def setupUI(self, _title, _label, _btn):
        self.setWindowTitle(_title)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(500, 300))
        self.btn_okay = QPushButton(_btn, self)
        self.btn_okay.setGeometry(int(500/2) -50, int(300/2) -50, 100, 100)
        self.btn_label = QPushButton(" ", self)
        self.btn_label.setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 50)
        self.label = QLabel(_label, self)
        self.label.setGeometry(5, -50, 150, 170)
        self.label = QLabel(" ", self)
        time.sleep(1)
    
    def stop(self):
        time.sleep(1)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":       
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=window.setupUI, args=("Title", "Label", "Button"))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=window.stop)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Widgets are not thread safe, they cannot be accessed nor created in external threads. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @musicmante. My apologies for the super late response. I forgot that I had asked this question. All I wanted to do was have a background timer running, which would trigger a function inside the MainWindow class upon completion. I figured out how to do it, and I'll post my code shortly:)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about this question. I figured out a solution to my problem and I've attached the code below.

I wanted to create a background timer that would not lockup my gui. I also wanted the timer to trigger a method inside the MainWindow class upon completion. The GUI looks like trash, but this was solely for test purposes.

I decided to create a separate class for my timer, which would inherit from QThread, and have it's method override the QThread run method. Following that, I made a method inside the Mainwindow class, which would start the timer thread and then trigger a message when that thread finishes. self.worker.finished.connect(self.timout_message) triggers the message method when the timeout occurs.

```py
import sys,time, threading
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

TIMEOUT_VALUE = 5

class Background_Timer(QThread):
    
    def run(self):
        count_timer = 0
        while count_timer < TIMEOUT_VALUE :
            time.sleep(1)
            count_timer += 1

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI("Title", "Label", "Okay")
      
    def setupUI(self, _title, _label, _btn):
        self.timeout()
        self.setWindowTitle(_title)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(500, 300))
        self.btn_okay = QPushButton(_btn, self)
        self.btn_okay.setGeometry(int(500/2) -50, int(300/2) -50, 100, 100)
        self.label = QLabel(_label, self)
        self.label.setGeometry(5, -50, 150, 170)
        self.label = QLabel(" ", self)
    
    def timeout(self): 
        '''Creates worker instance for timeout'''
        self.worker = Background_Timer()
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.timeout_message)
    
    def timeout_message(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Timeout", "A timeout has occured")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":       
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need for threading to do this, as [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) is perfectly capable of providing what you are asking: connect its `timeout` signal to a function that increments the count, and when it reaches the required amount stop the timer and call the other function.

Comment: Thank you, @musicmante. I'll remember this if I use pyqt again in the future - at the moment I'm just experimenting. Although, I do want to gain a thorough understanding pyqt. I find that youtube videos and web articles aren't very helpful. Are there any textbooks/courses that you would recommend?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, as I've learnt everything by myself. I know for a fact that there are some valid books, but I cannot suggest any because I've not read them. Perhaps, "Mastering GUI Programming with Python: Develop impressive cross-platform GUI applications with PyQt" by Alan D. Moore might be a good one, but I can tell you only because I've seen a couple of videos made by him and his approach seems quite valid. There are good tutorials (like those on [python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials), but they mostly cover basic aspects and not advanced concepts.

Comment: I usually discourage videos in general, not because video tutorials are bad, but because there are a lot of self proclaimed "gurus" that too often create videos based on generic and inexperienced knowledge: they seem to have been played around with a certain module/toolkit just a few weeks, and as a result they often provide bad suggestions because they didn't have time to understand everything required to *properly* teach how to use a certain tool. Their priority is to create content (and get revenue), not to *responsibly* teach how to do things. There are good videos, but they are rare.